# Facebook open graph doesn't work

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, open-graph-protocol

I have used open graph meta tags in my website

```
<meta name="og:description" content="My page descriptions ..." />
<meta name="og:title" content="سخت‌افزار20" />
<meta name="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="og:url" content="http://www.hardware20.com/" />
<meta name="og:image" content="http://www.hardware20.com/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
<meta name="og:site_name" content="hardware20"/>
<meta name="og:locale" content="fa-IR" />
```

But facebooke does not load Image & Descriptions, When I try to share a page.

I have tried debugging by open graph debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
But the debugger always said `Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.` (even with facebook examples!)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible that facebook API is having some issues?

Comment: @edvinas.me I have never tried the debugger before maybe this problem is temporary. but my code doesn't work.

Comment: Is it possible that something in your robots.txt would be blocking Facebook's scraper?

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht I wonder why https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ does not work with any URLs not just my website.

Comment: I just tried it on one of my websites, and it was working fine.

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht Would you please send me your debugger link like https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.imdb.com maybe my IP is blocked or something like this.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nathangiesbrecht.com works for me.... interestingly, when I click on your link I get the same error you were. But when I click the "Debug" button again, it works. Are you trying to access the debugger through a script of some type, or just using it normally through the web UI?

Comment: @nathangiesbrecht Thanks, still got `Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.` I used VPN (Because Facebook is not available in Iran!) maybe my VPN server is blocked by Facebook debugger, anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the site also hosted in Iran? It's possible that the requests are all being blocked as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that because your site is hosted in Iran (or [appears to be](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=www.hardware20.com)) Facebook is blocked from scraping it? Typically a call to the Facebook share API includes the page title and the URL and the rest is scraped by a crawl.

If the Iranian firewall blocks outbound requests to Facebook I don't see why it would allow inbound requests either.